# Not receive DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE broadcast when download complete

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager

I create an app with an update feature, my app is now able to detect the update and download it but when the download complete, DownloadReceiver is not triggered and I don't know why

I have a class AppUpdater like this:

```
class AppUpdater(private val context: Context) {
    private lateinit var apkUrl: String
    private var downloadId: Long = -1
    var isUpdateAvailable = mutableStateOf(false)

    val downloadManager: DownloadManager = context.getSystemService(DownloadManager::class.java)

    fun checkForUpdates() {
        HttpHandler.asyncHandle(Constant.UPDATE_URL, Constant.AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN, ::callback)
    }

    private fun callback(response: okhttp3.Response) {...}

    fun downloadApkFile() {
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(apkUrl))
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            .addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${Constant.AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN}")
            .addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/octet-stream")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                "MyApp.apk"
            )
            .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
        downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request)
    }

    inner class DownloadReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            Log.w("AppUpdater", "APK Download Complete")
            val id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1)
            if (id == downloadId) {...}
        }
    }
}
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml, I register this receiver:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AppUpdater$DownloadReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem could be that you register this receiver via manifest, and android has limitations to [this kind](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers) of registering or it may be fact that exported flag is set to `false`.

First try set this flag to `true` and if this not resolves issue try register receiver with context.

Comment: yeah, DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE is intent broadcast by system, not my app so I need to change export field to true. I fixed it a while ago but thank you